# Fixing invalid geometry (self intersection)

Tags: qgis, geometry, self-intersection

Attempted to extract raster by mask layer in QGIS 2.18.15 and for one of my shapefiles, the command could not be executed. The error message reads "Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 97.520362854004077 18.494590759277401 
ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid."

I executed the Check Validity function, and identified the source of this self-intersection.
[image: Self-intersection]

In trying to correct this 1 error, I have tried the following

- (1) added a zero distance buffer using QGIS default plugin
- (2) added a zero distance buffer using GRASS v.buffer.distance
- (3) used multiple permutations of GRASS's v.clean & v.clean.advanced

But none of the above has rectified this issue i.e. when I run the Check Validity function, the error still persists. I have browsed through several threads within this forum but their solutions don't seem to work for me.

Comment: To get rid of this goemetry problem you have to change the geometry in one of two ways: 1. Open up the polygon by moving the two touching vertices away from each other. 2. Create a proper hole by introducing a *bridge* across the area where the two vertices touches. I don't know if either method exist in modern GIS software.

Comment: Strange that buffer by zero hasn't worked in this case. What format are you storing this polygon in? If you are storing it as sqlite, geopackage or in PostGIS you could try st_makevalid?

Comment: zero distance buffer and v.clean should generally fix your issue. Is it possible to share your geometry? Another tool that I recommend is mapshaper.org - you will get a prompt to fix line intersections, try that and export to see if the issue gets fixed.

Comment: Could you compare these two geometries: `POLYGON (( 0 160, 60 160, 60 120, 30 120, 40 140, 20 140, 30 120, 0 120, 0 160 ))` and `POLYGON (( 30 120, 0 120, 0 160, 60 160, 60 120, 30 120 ), ( 30 120, 40 140, 20 140, 30 120 ))`? Which one QGIS does not like? Difference is if outer ring is touching itself at one point or if there is an inner ring that is touching the outer ring.

Comment: Topologically speaking, this isn't an error. It's called an *inversion*. Unfortunately, different packages handle the problem differently -- Esri tools would write that as a single ring, but others may require two rings (a "hole" touching at the edge).

Comment: Related 
 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137380/what-do-you-call-this-non-hole-edge-condition

Comment: Practically speaking, PostGIS and JTS consider the first version (outer ring that forms inversion) as invalid and from user's point of view it may be an error. But buffer with zero distance should correct/change the polygon. This does do it for me `select st_astext(
st_buffer(
st_geomfromtext('POLYGON (( 0 160, 60 160, 60 120, 30 120, 40 140, 20 140, 30 120, 0 120, 0 160 ))'),0));`

Comment: as well as v.clean, try the QGIS "fix geometries" - note that there are two options, QGIS and GEOS. Worth trying both.

Comment: @PhilBarlow It is stored as an ESRI shapefile. I will try saving it as those other formats and give it a try

Comment: @spatialthoughts How do I share my geometry with you? I tried mapshaper.org but the exported geometry still has that error

Comment: @StevenKay I have attempted to use v.clean and its functions, but it did not work. Also, i could not find the "fix geometries" function you suggested

Comment: @Vince Thank you for the clarification and useful link

Comment: @user30184 I tested both geometries using the Check Validity function, which revealed that the 1st geometry was invalid (with an "error"), while the 2nd one was valid. *note: I created the 2nd geometry by applying the Union function. 

Also, after using the zero distance buffer, the geometry is now valid (after checking its validity)

However, when i applied a zero distance buffer on my vector layer, the layer 'Buffer' does appear on the Legends list on the left, but, there is no visualizable layer that appears on the canvas (which I am guessing means that it did not perform correctly)

Comment: @Chau As it stands, at present, I know not the means to achieve that within QGIS (unfortunately)

Comment: +1 for Steven Kay's suggestion of QGIS "fix geometries" processing tool. I've been using this tool recently to clean up some old data to go into PostGIS and it works very well. You'll need QGIS 3.0 onwards though I believe.

Comment: This issue is now resolved, please refer to the edited post above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After downloading QGIS 3.2.1 'Bonn' and using the "Fix Geometries" function (which is described very similarly to ST_MakeValid in PostGIS), the previously invalid polygon is made valid i.e. it does not turn out to be invalid after using 'Check Validity'.

It seems though that the inversion is still present in the layer despite it being a valid polygon now. Fortunately for me, this inversion is much smaller than the spatial unit I am working on, and its influence on data quality as a whole is not markedly detrimental.

Thank you one and all.

Comment: If you answer your own question, you should still "Accept" it.